# TextView autoheight in a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to insert a TextView inside a Scrollview. The scrollview work but the content of TextView not show complete, because appear their scroll. I would show complete content of TextView without scroll.

[image]

file.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UITextView *detailTextView;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;    
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

-(void)setTextViewForRecipes: (Recipe *)theRecipe;

@end
```

file.m

```
@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize  scroller;

-(void) setTextViewForRecipe:(Recipe *)theRecipe
{
 [detailTextView setText:theRecipe.detail]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
CGRect frame = detailTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = detailTextView.contentSize.height;
detailTextView.frame = frame;
[scroller setContentSize: CGSizeMake(280, detailTextView.frame.origin.y + detailTextView.frame.size.height + 10)];    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea in `viewDidLoad` by setting `detailTextView`'s frame height to its `contentSize` height.  But you need do that after you set the text of the view, and of course you need to adjust the scroller's `contentSize` again.

```
-(void) setTextViewForRecipe:(Recipe *)theRecipe
{
    detailTextView.text = theRecipe.detail;
    CGRect frame = detailTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = detailTextView.contentSize.height;
    detailTextView.frame = frame;
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 10 + CGRectGetMaxY(frame));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you shouldn't add it to a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

As bandejapaisa [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917607/534888), it's usually not necessary to wrap a `UITextView` inside a `UIScrollView`, because the textView can scroll by itself.

If, however, you really find this necessary, you can find out the size of the text if it were rendered with a certain font:

```
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSizeOfYourTextView]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(widthOfYourTextView, MAXFLOAT)
                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeOfYourTextView];
```

This will find out the height. Adapt to your needs, but be warned: This gets a little hackery, and you'll probably need to do some trial and error before you achieve the desired outcome.